# Objectify Ref<> with @Load is not working with ofy().load().group()

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I have a problem Ref<> usage with @Load. Basically I made a copy paste from Objectify website to test @Load annotation with Load Groups.

```
@Entity
public static class Thing {
    public static class Partial {}
    public static class Everything extends Partial {}
    public static class Stopper {}

    @Id Long id;
    @Load(Partial.class) Ref<Other> withPartial;
    @Load(Everything.class) Ref<Other> withEveryhthing;
    @Load(unless=Stopper.class) Ref<Other> unlessStopper;

    public Ref<Other> getWithPartial() {
        return withPartial;
    }

    public void setWithPartial(Ref<Other> withPartial) {
        this.withPartial = withPartial;
    }

    public Ref<Other> getWithEveryhthing() {
        return withEveryhthing;
    }

    public void setWithEveryhthing(Ref<Other> withEveryhthing) {
        this.withEveryhthing = withEveryhthing;
    }

    public Ref<Other> getUnlessStopper() {
        return unlessStopper;
    }

    public void setUnlessStopper(Ref<Other> unlessStopper) {
        this.unlessStopper = unlessStopper;
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the following code.

```
Other other = new Other();

Key<Other> otherKey = ofy().save().entity(other).now();

Thing thing = new Thing();
thing.setWithPartial(Ref.create(otherKey));

Key<Thing> thingKey = ofy().save().entity(thing).now();

Thing t = ofy().load().key(thingKey).now();

System.out.println("Is loaded: " + t.getWithPartial().isLoaded());
```

Without writing ofy().load().group(Partial.class).key(thingKey).now(); other entity still loads into session. However in documentation it needs group class to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `isLoaded()` method tests whether the entity is in the session cache. Since you just `save()`d the entity, it's already in the session cache.

If you want to test the behavior of load groups, you need to `ofy().clear()` the cache.